# How to Create Custom Dashboard for my Laundry Website?

Tags: plugins, login

Just to give you background, I have a local business and a WordPress website for it. The website helps my customers schedule a pick and drop for their laundry. What I want to accomplish is that:

1. Customer should be able to login/register to my website.
2. Check their history.
3. Schedule a pick/drop for laundry
4. Give feedback or suggestions.

But since I am new to WordPress, not sure where to begin. Can somebody push me in right direction.

How can I enable login/register for customers and show them a separate customer dashboard where they can check their history, Schedule for laundry or Give feedback or suggestions?

I understand this is a big project, just need enough stuff to study.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpewss appointment plugin to slove the issue
It will let yu schedule booking in your site
Wp appointment+ will also let you social login